# Detect collision or overlapping items

Tags: jquery, html, collision-detection, draggable, overlap

I'm trying to create a simple drag and drop item inventory game and, as you can see from the JSBin example, I have 4 colored boxes that, if you click, will appear in the inventory footer slots. Once I have clicked the items in the inventory footer slot, I can drag them around the slot area.

The problem I'm facing now is that some items can be combined with one another. How can I know the `id` of the items I'm combining? I need to detect the collision between the two div's? Please advice, thanks.

```
function collision($div1, $div2) {
        var x1 = $div1.offset().left;
        var y1 = $div1.offset().top;
        var h1 = $div1.outerHeight(true);
        var w1 = $div1.outerWidth(true);
        var b1 = y1 + h1;
        var r1 = x1 + w1;
        var x2 = $div2.offset().left;
        var y2 = $div2.offset().top;
        var h2 = $div2.outerHeight(true);
        var w2 = $div2.outerWidth(true);
        var b2 = y2 + h2;
        var r2 = x2 + w2;

        if (b1 < y2 || y1 > b2 || r1 < x2 || x1 > r2) return false;
        return true;
    }
```

[**Here's the JSBin**](http://jsbin.com/kamabobu/1)

*Edit : I manage to detect the collision of 2 div's using the function above. Thanks..

Try the dragging the red to the yellow box or vice versa...

[**Here's the updated JSBin**](http://jsbin.com/kamabobu/2)

Comment: Have you tried to create a collision detection system or something like it? If yes, please put the **relevant** JS code in the question because the link can break in the future.

Comment: @TiagoMarinho..i manage to solve the problem...i'll update the bin file for others...